# Utilizar la funcion .sort() cuando un arreglo puede contener valores nulos en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, ordenamiento

Busco hacer una función que acepte valores nulos, evalúe una secuencia de números y, si la secuencia esta vacía, debe devolverme la misma secuencia vacía. Si esta contiene algun valor nulo, debe devolver igualmente la secuencia vacía. En el caso de que no este vacía ni tenga valores nulos, debe ordenar los valores de mayor a menor.

```
fun ordenar(collection : Array<Int?>): Array<Int?>{

    var res : Array<Int?> = arrayOf(1)
    if (!collection.contains(null)){
        if(collection.isNotEmpty()){

        }
        else{
            res = arrayOf()
        }
    }
    else{
        res = arrayOf()
    }

    return res
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste a tu pregunta por favor, revisa [ask] y agrega mayor información a tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin tiene varios métodos que nos ayudan con la nulabilidad y con la ordenación. Además para ser más correctos, podríamos subir el `return` al inicio del if, que es algo que queda mejor.

El fragmento de código que haría lo que tú deseas podría ser el siguiente:

```
fun ordenar(coleccion : Array<Int?>) : Array<Int> {
   return if(coleccion.isNullOrEmpty() || coleccion.contains(null)) {
       arrayOf()
   }else{
       coleccion.filterNotNull().sortedByDescending{it}.toTypedArray()
   }
}
```

Como podrás ver, en la rama `else` primero nos quedamos con los elementos not null, para después poder aplicar el método que los ordena descendientemente.